# How to pack python flask_socketio app with pyinstaller

Tags: python

I tried official demo code:

```
#test.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

it runs well, but when packed with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

and then run test.exe, I got:

```
Z:\test\dist>test2.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 119, in __init__
  File "site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 144, in init_app
  File "site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 72, in __init__
  File "site-packages\engineio\server.py", line 100, in __init__
ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified
test2 returned -1
```

is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

add 'engineio.async_gevent' to hiddenimports in spec file.
you may refer to: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/35